# Convert a string to another Python class

Tags: python, rest, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Is there anyway to create another class for a Model?

For example, I have model.py, which one of the class inside contains:

```
class Customers(ndb.Model):
  lastname = ndb.StringProperty()
  firstname = ndb.StringProperty()
  license = ndb.StringProperty()
  birthdate = ndb.DateProperty()
  remarks = ndb.TextProperty()
```

I know I can get the models using `dir(model)`, and it outputs something like:

```
['Customers', 'CustomerAddresses','Whatever','__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'ndb']
```

However, is there any way that I can use these string inside `dir(model)` to automatically generate another class, like:

```
class RestCustomers(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  #some code that gets the model class attributes and displays the json string 
  customers = # customer attributes from model
  self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = "application/json"
  self.response.write(json.dumps(customers))
```

I'm not sure if it is possible, but kind of like the way javascript works, wherein you say something like

```
var models = dir(models); // which is an array
var class = "Rest"+models[0];
```

or something like that...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
from google.appengine.ext.ndb import metadata
class RestCustomers(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    customers = metadata.get_properties_of_kind(Customers)
    self.response.headers['Content-Type'] = "application/json"
    self.response.write(json.dumps(customers))
```

For more information, see the [documentation about metadata](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/ndb/metadata). I am not completely sure how `get_properties_of_kind` expects to get the `kind` argument so try it out.

Answer (score 0):

You can use:

```
self.__setattr__(variable_name, value)
```

...try something like this. Though I'm not sure exactly what you want. I don't think you know what you want ;) Usually if you have to hack something together like this, your idea/design is incorrect.

```
class NewClass:
    def __init__(self, inherits):
        for k, v in inherits.__dict__.items():
            self.__setattr__(k, v)
```